# How to view log files while using Memgraph with Docker?

Tags: docker, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I am using Memgraph with Docker and I want to access today's log files. What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the log files you first need to enter the Docker container where Memgraph is running. Then follow these steps:

1. Execute the command `docker ps`
   to find the ID of the container, **CONTAINER_ID.**
2. Then, execute the command
   `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash`
3. Now you can use the command
   `cat /var/log/memgraph/memgraph_2022-03-03.log`

to check today's log file.